# Import Error: paho.mqtt.client not found

Tags: python, docker, mqtt, paho

I am creating a docker containing python and php. I am writing a python script to connect to a MQTT broker residing in another docker.

In my dockerfile I ensure that I install the paho client by using the following commands:

```
RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev 
RUN apt-get install -y libffi-dev 
RUN apt-get install -y libssl-dev

ADD https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py /tmp/get-pip.py 
RUN cat /tmp/get-pip.py | python3 
RUN pip install paho-mqtt 
RUN pip install python-etcd
```

However when I run the python script I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named paho.mqtt.client
```

The docker installation does not show any error with regards to paho-mqtt installation.
It will be great if someone can guide on this.

Comment: You seem to install it via python3 — are you sure you are staring python3?

Comment: Did you get any warnings installing `paho-mqtt`? Can you find `paho mqtt` in you `pip list`?

Comment: @frlan I tried with python 2.7 but now the script does not even seem to execute. Should I attach my entire Dockerfile?

Comment: @Eddie No I do not get any error or warning during paho mqtt installation.

Comment: @Sid411 I think `mqtt` is not being installed properly. Could you verify it from the `pip list` command? What do you get when you run the `python --version` command? I can install and import it with no problem in Python 3.6.

Comment: @Eddie the pip list shows following list 

argparse (1.2.1) 
chardet (2.0.1) 
colorama (0.2.5) 
paho-mqtt (1.2)
html5lib (0.999) 
pip (1.5.4) 
requests (2.2.1) 
setuptools (3.3) 
six (1.5.2)
 urllib3 (1.7.1) 
virtualenv (1.11.4) 
wheel (0.24.0) 
wsgiref (0.1.2) 

And python version is 2.7

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think I have found the problem,

You have installed `Python3` but for some reason the interpreter defaults to version 2.7 in Linux.

Try using `pip3 install paho-mqtt python-etcd` instead.

Or if it does not work, you can literally copy and paste the `paho` folder from your `Python2.7` `site-packages` folder to your `Python3` `site-packages` folder. I have just verified `paho-mqtt 1.2` for `Python2` is exactly the same as `paho-mqtt 1.2` for `Python3` using a `Meld` diff tool. Please note, when you directly copy and paste `pip list` will not display the package you copied.

`site-packages` are usually inside your system `lib` folder. It depends upon how `Python` is installed. In my case everything is inside `$HOME/.pyenv` folder.

Remember `Python2` has it's own `site-packages` folder and `Python3` has it's own `site-packages` folder where `Python` searches for the packages. Sometimes if you are using a `Debian` based Linux distro please make sure to check inside the `dist-packages` folder as well to see if you can find the package you are looking for.

Comment: Is site packages same as dist packages?

Comment: They are essentially the same thing. I don't know why but the Debian based package managers love to use `dist-packages` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The copy paste thing worked. It is not giving that error.

Comment: @Sid411 Im glad it helped. Please be aware it is not `pip` friendly to manually copy and paste.

Answer (score 4):

You can try install Paho lib:

```
git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python
```

Once you have the code, it can be installed from your repository as well:

```
cd paho.mqtt.python
python setup.py install
```