# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paho'

Tags: python, import, pip, mqtt, libraries

I am trying to make connection with my raspberry Pi and my PC windows through MQTT protocol. And I have a problem I cant solve on my PC - I can t import library that I have installed to my program:

`import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt`

Results in the error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paho'`

The topic was already issued here ([Import Error: paho.mqtt.client not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480256/import-error-paho-mqtt-client-not-found)), but solution doesnt work for me.

I see it in the python folder:

C:\Users\mhucl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client

I see it in the pip list. But the program can t find it. Do you know where could be the problem? I use python version 3.10.3. I tried it on different PC aswell and the same result. I followed all solutions on youtube, forums and nothing. Thank you very much.

Here are screenshots if someone would like to see:

https://uschovna.cz/zasilka/WLUWM5TNP7HP7GDG-XKP/UCKZFIZHCI

Comment: `python --version` ? `pip --version` ? `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` ? Is `C:\Users\mhucl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages` in the path?

Comment: python version is 3.10.3,  pip 22.0.4. And yes its in the path.

Comment: I think I got it. I didn t realize that spyder IDE has different python library. So I copy paste the paho library from python to the spyder folder. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install paho-mqtt
```

https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/

I solved my error by using this command