# No module named 'paho.mqtt'; 'paho' is not a package

Tags: python, paho

resolved
I have set up a conda environment with anaconda, with python 3.9 and paho-mqtt 1.6.1. I have also tested an Environment that worked for someone else but it doesn't work on my System. Other packages work, like numpy.

The code fails at the first row
`import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt` wit the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paho.mqtt'; 'paho' is not a package`.

Does anyone have a solution or at least some ideas i could try?

For example if i create a new conda env with `conda env --create env python=3.9`, and then try to run `import numpy` it obviously doenst run. Then i do `pip install numpy` and run it again and it works. Though if i do the same with `import paho.mqtt`  it doesn't work even after `pip install paho-mqtt`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import Error: paho.mqtt.client not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480256/import-error-paho-mqtt-client-not-found)

Comment: No i tried all the different installation methods in there already. The weird thing is i had it working in my first environment. But now i needed to set up a new one for a different project and it does not work.

Comment: Because you have to install it again, you exit your virtual env hence the package is not available anymore

Comment: I did install it again in the new environment.

Comment: Do you have a script named `paho.py`, by any chance?

Comment: Yes. I changed it to test.py and it works... 
Why is that the Problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paho.mqtt'; 'paho' is not a package
```

may also occur if you have named the main program file you created as `paho.py` and try to run it as `python paho.py` **or** another file has the name `paho.py` in the same folder from which you run your program. Python will consider your program file as a module and try to find something in it that is naturally not in it. About where Python is looking for modules, see [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) (citate: *"...if path[0] is the empty string, which directs Python to **search modules in the current directory first**..."*).

In this case, **rename your program file so that its name does not equal with the name of the imported module**.